# How to compile an Unreal Engine plugin and update it current UE version?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am using Unreal Engine 4.24.3. I want to check out this plugin: https://github.com/jinyuliao/Grid, it says it's been updated to 4.24. Does that mean it's not fully compatible? His instructions are vague, or I don't know enough about Unreal to figure it out.

Directions:

> Clone this project to ${YourProject}/Plugins/
>
> Generate project file
>
> Compile

I've done the first one. Now my project won't open. I get a message saying "The following modules are missing or built with a different engine version: GridRuntime GridEditor

They are both in the Source folder. I don't know what Generate project file means, and I don't know what Compile means. I have VS Studio 2019, but I only use Blueprints in UE so I haven't worked with it. Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: If you right click your uproject it should bring up a context menu with "Generate project files" as a option, you wanna click that. That should create a visual studio project in the same folder. You can then open that and then make sure your target is development editor or something to that effect ( will be displayed at the top of vs somewhere ). And then you should be good to build, I think the default hotkeys are either F7 or ctrl+shift+b. Though it will also be under a context menu at the top. (Build will compile as part of the process but do some other necessary bits too)

Comment: So it compiles as part of building the overall project? Thanks. It's saying I don't have any C++ files, and I need to add one in the editor. I'll give that a try and see if it works.

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 is not compatible with Unreal 4.24 or 4.25. You have to use Visual Studio 2017.

As for generating your project files that's pretty vague. I suspect he means the Visual Studio files. This requires you right-clicking (I'm assuming PC and not Mac here) on your project .uproject file and selecting "Generate Visual Studio files" from the resulting context menu. There is a way to do this stuff from the command line but I lack the space in this comment for instructions that detailed.

Comment: @RichardRobertson That's not correct. From the docs: "As of version 4.22, Unreal Engine does not support VS 2015. Unreal Engine still uses VS 2017 by default, but also supports VS 2019." - https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Programming/Development/VisualStudioSetup/index.html

Comment: @jehuty Thanks for that correction. My project lead told me that (I was out of town and was out of touch with version updates) and I assumed he knew what he was talking about. I'll pass this on. Having to maintain two different versions of VS has been a PIA!